# A bear of a different colour

Tags: mathematics, geometry, algebra

Here is a stunning new version of the famous bear problem. IT IS NOT A DUPLICATE, OR LATERAL THINKING. MATHEMATICS REQUIRED.

A photographer stepped out of their tent with a camera and walked:

- 1 km south, then
- 1 km east, then
- 1 km north & **finally**
- 1 km west.

Then the photographer was back *exactly* at the tent, and took a nice photograph of a bear.

What color was that bear?

(There are multiple possible answers. Assume a perfectly spherical planet. Trigonometry & algebra required for full credit!)

If I ever get to one of these regions, I definitely want to execute one of these circuits. So I am just planning ahead :-)

Comment: Can you edit the image of the bear color map into the puzzle if it is a required step to solve the puzzle?

Comment: Hi justhalf. No it's not essential, and I don't know who owns that map. Mainly this is a mathematical problem, so I've removed the link which might be distracting for some. Looking for a bear map online can be part of the fun for those who care :-)

Comment: This question is a duplicate: [Ten miles south, east, north and west](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/100170/ten-miles-south-east-north-and-west)

Comment: Thanks Nuclear Hoagie: I think you're right, that's a duplicate, although no-one has really crunched the algebra in that one. Just "intermediate value theorem" blah.

Comment: Yeah, gj hoagie, this was definitely what i'd seen but was still searching for bears

Answer (score 3):

I think I've this somewhere around here. You are positioned at

> the equator, the only place where the "distortion" the original riddle poses is symmetrical enough to be nonexistent. Speaking of nonexistent, that's what an equator bear and its color are.

Correction:

> You are actually at such a place where your journey is symmetrical with regard to the equator plane. That is, you start 0.5 km north of the equator.
>  When moving east or west, you do the same arc because you are at the same latitude.

Comment: The correction is one solution, but you're wrong about the bears. And is near equator the only solution?

Comment: There was another. OK, i'll try to find the other post, the other was complex.

Answer (score 2):

Ignoring bears and just focussing on the geometry part, There should be

> infinitely many solutions both near the north and neanr the south pole.
>  All we need to do is find two longitudes that are a surface kilometer apart and such that a kilometer on the circles at these longitudes translates into the same number of longitudes modulo a full round. There are obviously infinitely many such pairs.

Comment: Yep. Can you find the formula for the latitudes though, in terms of the ratio of the walk distance to the radius of the Earth? It's not that complicated. There is a simplifying trick which is fun

Comment: Can't be bothered to be honest. Looks tedious and unrewarding to me.

Comment: Sorry, I suppose that may have sounded a bit harsher than intended.